# Arguments for tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want two tasks in gradle. `runMocked` whichs runs a docker-container (named `tomcat-mock`) in a "mocked" mode. And `run` which runs a other container (`tomcat`).

The `build.gradle`

```
task runMocked {
    dependsOn(composeUp)

    dockerCompose {
        startedServices = ['tomcat-mock']
    }

}

task run {
    dependsOn(composeUp)

    dockerCompose {
        startedServices = ['tomcat']
    }

}

dockerCompose {

    // like 'docker-compose -f <file>'; default is empty
    useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/docker-compose.local.yml']
// ....
}
```

Everytime when `dockerCompose` will start, then it uses the `startedServices` that are definied in last task (of the whole `build.gradle` file).
For the example-build.gradle it uses `tomcat`-container. There is no difference when the task `runMocked` or `run` was started.

I dont see the problem. Have anyone a hint for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This site helps me out: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html

New `gradle.build`-file

```
tasks.register("runMocked") {
    dependsOn composeUp

    dockerCompose {
        startedServices = ['tomcat-mock']
    }
}


tasks.register("run") {
    dependsOn composeUp

    dockerCompose {
        startedServices = ['tomcat']
    }

}
```